# Node repl with async await

Tags: node.js, async-await, read-eval-print-loop, ecmascript-2017

I would like to add support to async/await to node repl

Following this issue: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8382

I've tried to use this one https://github.com/paulserraino/babel-repl but it is missing async await suppport

I would like to use this snippet

```
const awaitMatcher = /^(?:\s*(?:(?:let|var|const)\s)?\s*([^=]+)=\s*|^\s*)(await\s[\s\S]*)/;
const asyncWrapper = (code, binder) => {
  let assign = binder ? `root.${binder} = ` : '';
  return `(function(){ async function _wrap() { return ${assign}${code} } return _wrap();})()`;
};

// match & transform
const match = input.match(awaitMatcher);
if(match) {
  input = `${asyncWrapper(match[2], match[1])}`;
}
```

How can I add this snippet to a custom eval on node repl?

Example in node repl:

```
> const user = await User.findOne();
```

Comment: What about using ordinary Node 7 REPL with `--harmony`?

Comment: node --harmony-async-await on Node 7 REPL do not work

Comment: Well, it should. I would suggest to check Node version. Obviously, `await` should be inside `async` function.

Comment: Are you asking how to write a patch that solves https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/13209?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169542/how-to-resolve-promises-when-using-app-with-repl

Answer (score 88):

As of [node ^10](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/13209#issuecomment-385852791), you can use the following flag when starting the repl:

```
node --experimental-repl-await
$ await myPromise()
```

Comment: Working great in node 10 and 12, and can be set in bashrc/zshrc with `export NODE_OPTIONS="--experimental-repl-await"` (so you always have it while debugging).

Comment: Starting with node v16.6.0 (Jul 29, 2021. [changelog](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v16.6.0/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V16.md) & [commit a082a705b](https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/a082a705b391712758ec9e296ca62653b458f841)), async-await in repl is enabled by default. You can opt out by passing [`--no-experimental-repl-await`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/cli.html#--no-experimental-repl-await) .

Answer (score 8):

There is the project https://github.com/ef4/async-repl:

```
$ async-repl
async> 1 + 2
3
async> 1 + await new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r(2), 1000))
3
async> let x = 1 + await new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r(2), 1000))
undefined
async> x
3
async>
```

Another option, slightly onerous to start but with a great UI, is to use the Chrome Devtools:

```
$ node --inspect -r esm
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/b4fb341e-da9d-4276-986a-46bb81bdd989
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
> Debugger attached.
```

(I am using the [esm](https://github.com/standard-things/esm) package here to allow Node to parse `import` statements.)

Then you go to `chrome://inspect` in Chrome and you will be able to connect to the `node` instance. Chrome Devtools has top-level await, great tab-completion etc.

Comment: it's possible to see a demo?.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to preprocess the command and wrap it in a async function if 
there is an await syntax outside async function

this https://gist.github.com/princejwesley/a66d514d86ea174270210561c44b71ba is the final solution

Comment: Should we expect a promise or the result? The REPL does not hang until it gets the result you need to pause and resume it somehow, but afaik. that is not supported, at least `repl.pause()` exited by me. Another issue here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/13209